# Sorting NSMutableDictionary data

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

In my application I am having a dictionary which contains Keys A-Z ie 26 characters which are not in sorted ie for eg A,B,C,......
I want to Sort first The dictionary keys alphabetically  and also the sort the data related to each key and then again store that in same dictionary.

```
NSArray *myKeys = [mGlossaryDict allKeys];
NSArray *op = [myKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

until now here I have an mGlossaryDict which is an Mutabledictionary which is sorted but i need to sort the data from each of the key.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *myKeys = [mGlossaryDict allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [myKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for(id key in sortedKeys) {
    id object = [myGlossaryDict objectForKey:key];
    [sortedValues addObject:object];
}
```

Comment: Here Keys are sorted but the data inside the keys are not Sorted.

Comment: Your question does not explain clearly what you want to do. Sorting an NSDictionary makes no sense, so I guessed you want an array with all the values sorted by key.

Comment: As if this is to load the dictionary in tableview so i need sorting as if i retrive the data from database and filled the dictionary, Now the data from the dictionary is not showing in sorted order. eg. "a" and  "A" here  "A" is displayed first means all the characters with first character capital are displayed first and then the rest.